# Problem importing .csv file into sql server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv, mariadb

The file is located on my Website and i want to import it to a sql server, but everytime i run the php script it adds the table, but not the information. I tried running it like this

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/u831625604/domains/andreiilinescu.com/public_html/stoc.csv'
 INTO TABLE stock
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
 IGNORE 1 ROWS
(denumire,um,cod_bare,categorie,stoc,pret)
```

This is the whole code:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "u831625604_a";
$password = "Highschooldxd1";
$db = "u831625604_a";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password , $db) or die("Connect failed: %s\n". $conn -> error);
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stock` (
    `denumire` VARCHAR(255),
    `um` VARCHAR(255),
    `cod_bare` VARCHAR(255),
    `categorie` VARCHAR(255),
    `stoc` VARCHAR(255),
    `pret`VARCHAR(255)
 );";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$sql = "
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/u831625604/domains/andreiilinescu.com/public_html/stoc.csv'
 INTO TABLE stock
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
 IGNORE 1 ROWS
(denumire,um,cod_bare,categorie,stoc,pret)
";
```

Comment: why can't you load the data through the panel? localhost/phpmyadmin

Comment: I am writing a script to have it imported once every hour.

Comment: What;s the nature of the problem?

Comment: It does not load the data in my table and i don't know why. It may have something to do with the file path.

Comment: Am I right in the assumption that you don't understand the code up there, and are not interested in understanding the code at all?